# Keep only null values in column row pandas

Tags: pandas

This should be very simple but i'm hitting a wall, i want to create a copy of a dataframe where only the null values in a certain column are present. I've tried inverse dropna and the below, neither work

```
new_df=pd.isnull(df.column)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print df.loc[pd.isnull(df).any(1),:]
```

Sample:

```
print df
       a  b     c    d
123  1.0  7  M024  NaN
123  2.0  9  M024  2.0
125  5.0  0  M024  1.0
127  7.0  4  M025  1.0
129  NaN  2  M024  1.0

print pd.isnull(df)
         a      b      c      d
123  False  False  False   True
123  False  False  False  False
125  False  False  False  False
127  False  False  False  False
129   True  False  False  False

print pd.isnull(df).any(1)
123     True
123    False
125    False
127    False
129     True
dtype: bool

print df.loc[pd.isnull(df).any(1),:]
       a  b     c    d
123  1.0  7  M024  NaN
129  NaN  2  M024  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you, does that allow me to specify a column subset, i want to copy  the entire dataframe where  the rows where for that one column are null or NaN

Comment: Catches everything for me where the records are objects; `df2=df1.loc[pd.isnull(df1).any(1),:]`

Comment: What kind of object? Where return `print pd.isnull(df)`  values `True`?

Comment: A python object, picks up as true / false.

Comment: `NLUDDataLDN_to_postcode2=NLUDData_CleanLDN.loc[pd.isnull(NLUDData_CleanLDN).any(1),:]`

Comment: Hmmm, I think solution is find how select data where object is `NaN`. And if function `isnull` doesnt work properly, maybe some other condition is necessary.

Comment: I've got part way but my brain has ground to a halt after being on this all day `CleanDF['NLUD_Postcode'].fillna(99, inplace=True)` replaces my nulls, `value_list = ['99']` & `Test = CleanDF[CleanDF.NLUD_Postcode.isin(value_list)]` doesnt quite work as returns a series not new dataframe

Comment: fixed; `Test2 = CleanDF[CleanDF.NLUD_Postcode == 99]` was missing part, not pretty or pythonic

Comment: Super. I am glad it works. Btw, my brain is ruined too. Nice day and good luck. If you want you can upvote my and Alexander solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To filter down just to the rows and columns that contain a NaN value, use `loc` and specify difference axis values using `any()` (the default value is 0 for columns).

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df.iat[0, 0] = np.nan
df.iat[-1, -1] = np.nan

>>> df
          A         B         C         D         E
0       NaN  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558
1 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599
2  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
3  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096
4 -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165       NaN

>>> df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), df.isnull().any()]
         A         E
0      NaN  1.867558
4 -2.55299       NaN
```

Comment: Hmm on mine this is leaving both NaN and other values, the records are objects

Comment: It returns a dataframe where there is a NaN in either the row or the column.  Conversely, if filters out rows and columns that do not have NaN values.

Comment: it works on your example with that dataframe but not on the actual, as discussed with jezrael below